# How to debug when deploying to capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I am getting this error when deploying to production server:

```
$ cap production deploy
    triggering load callbacks
  * ←[32m2013-02-16 00:06:00 executing `production'←[0m
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * ←[32m2013-02-16 00:06:00 executing `multistage:ensure'←[0m
  * ←[32m2013-02-16 00:06:00 executing `deploy'←[0m
  * ←[32m2013-02-16 00:06:00 executing `deploy:update'←[0m
 ** transaction: start
  * ←[32m2013-02-16 00:06:00 executing `deploy:update_code'←[0m
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    ←[33mexecuting locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:user/app.git
production"←[0m
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 3350ms←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "if [ -d /var/www/app/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/
www/app/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q ori
gin && git reset -q --hard f736340ecbsadasd948234f370c9d2bb && git clean
 -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:user/app.git /var/www/app/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/app/shared/cached-copy && git checko
ut -q -b deploy f736340ecasdsadasf795761f370c9d2bb; fi"←[0m
    servers: ["x"]
Password:
    [x] executing command
 ** ←[31m[x :: out] error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission d
enied←[0m
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 570ms←[0m
*** [←[34mdeploy:update_code←[0m] ←[34mrolling back←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "rm -rf /var/www/app/releases/20130215230611; true"←[0m
    servers: ["x"]
    [x] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 176ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/app/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/www/
app/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin
&& git reset -q --hard f736340342af1bsad79453761f370c9d2bb && git clean -q
-d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:user/app.git /var/www/app
o/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/app/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -
q -b deploy f736340ecb6af1bgaasd5549d2bb; fi'" on x
$
```

But the error is not that important it just tells me that there is a problem with the gem file/bundle install.

How is it possible get an more detailed error log, where I can see precise where the problem lies.

Comment: you need to show all the output, most likely all thee required information is already there

Comment: @mpapis - I have updated the question with the log..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you have ran one of the commands with `sudo`, this lead to wrong permissions for `/var/www/app/shared/cached-copy/.git/FETCH_HEAD`, the easiest fix would be most likely to clean whole directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/www/app/shared/cached-copy
```

If the problem repeats for other directories then try:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: /var/www/app
```

Comment: I found out it was some permisson problems by running cap production deploy:check. Now I just get an error because of RVM is not loaded.